# VHDL storing individual numbers of a timer into an array to display in a seven segment display

Tags: vhdl

So, I have a code that shows me a timer that counts up perfectly fine and has a working multiplexer, I now want to add a way to basically store the individual value of each number (1, 10 and 100s ) so I can display them. My VHDL knowledge is really basic but here is an example :

```
signal n ; integer ;= 0;   --this is the lap counter
type laptimeone is array (integer range <>) of integer;
type laptimeten is array (integer range <>) of integer;
type laptimehundred is array (integer range <>) of integer;
```

where laptimeone, ten and hundred is each of the digits I want to save in my array. and n is just there to help me find my way back to that array with another process.

```
begin
if (StopState = '0') then
--counter, in seconds. with pause.
  if(second_clk'event and secondclk='1') then
      bcd0 <= one;
      bcd1 <= ten;
        bcd2 <= hundred;
        one <= one + 1;   
   if (one = 9) then 
        one <= 0; 
      ten <= ten +1;
    end if;  
    if (ten = 9) and (one = 9) then               
        ten <= 0;
        hundred <= hundred + 1;
    end if;  
    if (hundred= 9) and (ten= 9) and (one= 9) then   
        hundred <= 0;
    end if;   

 end if;
elsif (StopState ='1')
laptimeone(n)<= one
laptimeten(n) <= ten
laptimehundred(n) <= hundred
```

Now I am using some logic I know from other programming languages, but my endgame is simply that when stopstate is 1 , the timer stops,  and the last numbers for one,ten and hundred are stored in my array depending on N which is a lap that I will change on another process.

How would I declare and initialize the arrays that could help me ? and am I able to do what I want to do in here in VHDL where I move my way around an array when storing and reading data by simply using that N ?

Comment: I know this question is quite old now, but are you still interested in getting an answer?

Comment: I do not need it anymore, but I am however interested in how can this be possible, I ended up changing the scope of my program a bit and it fills the required function. but I want to see what I can do in this case.